# starting with mysql on an ubuntu server php

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I am new to mysql but have recently tried doing some tutorials to advance my knowledge. Anyways I installed mysql on my ubuntu server as well as phpmyadmin. They both seem to work just fine, I created a database in phpmyadmin called "test" as well as a table called "teddy".
I put data into the table and I can clearly see it through phpmyadmin.

Now when I try accessing this database via a php script on my ubuntu server, nothing happens. Literally nothing. It reacts the same way as if I had a syntax error (a quick load with nothing displayed).

This is my code... If anyone knows where my mistake is it would be much appreciated.

Thank you

```
 <?php

   $username='root';
    $password='***';
    $database='test';


   @$db= mysqli_connect('localhost', $username, $password, $database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo 'Error: Could not connect';
exit;

 }

 $query= "select * from test";

$result= $db->query($query);

$num_results= $result->num_rows;

echo $num_results;


  ?>
```

EDITED (based on drew 010)

Problem was the table was not called test but teddy so putting in this code worked.
"SELECT * FROM 'teddy'";

```
$db= new mysqli('localhost', $username, $password, $database);

 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
echo 'Error: Could not connect';
exit;

 }

 $query = "SELECT * FROM 'teddy'";

  $result = $db->query($query);
 if ($result) {
  $num_results = $result->num_rows;

  echo $num_results;
    } else {
  echo "Query failed: {$db->error}\n";
   }


  ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$result= $db->query($query);` is probably returning false for some reason.

Try:

```
$query = "select * from teddy";

$result = $db->query($query);
if ($result) {
    $num_results = $result->num_rows;

    echo $num_results;
} else {
    echo "Query failed: {$db->error}\n";
}
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues

Comment: @drew010 Good call, Finally got something to output on the screen. Its telling me now Query failed: Table 'test.test' doesn't exist. Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Did you actually create the database called test, and create a table called test within that database?

Comment: @drew010 The error was the fact that the table was not called test but teddy so "SELECT * FROM teddy";  Did the trick. Thank you! accepted answer

Comment: Good catch, sorry I didn't remember you actually said the table name was teddy in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use mysql but I'm guessing because you're using mysqli_connect. Try mysql_connect instead

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: This is the original extension designed to allow you to develop PHP applications that interact with a MySQL database. The mysql extension provides a procedural interface and is intended for use only with MySQL versions older than 4.1.3. This extension can be used with versions of MySQL 4.1.3 or newer, but not all of the latest MySQL server features will be available.  `If you are using MySQL versions 4.1.3 or later it is strongly recommended that you use the mysqli extension instead.`  Src: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php

Comment: No problem, newer code will use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) for mysql connections.

Comment: I'm a PDO person myself but I use postgres :)

Comment: Good choice, I really wanted to use PG for my latest project but unfortunately management went with MySQL because we needed something that wasn't available yet and didn't want to run with the beta as 9 wasn't released yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
@$db= mysqli_connect('localhost', $username, $password, $database);
```

should be

```
$db= new mysqli('localhost', $username, $password, $database);
```

Comment: The @ in front of $db will just suppress the error if the connect fails, but it is valid; and he is checking to make sure the connection succeeded on the next line.

Comment: I have added my edited code based on drew010 suggestion and the new error being outputed. Thanks!